# SharePoint Column Types

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I'm requesting SharePoint Columns using MS Graph and need to understand the type of each column.

Unfortunately, not all column types are support in Microsoft Graph. For example, Hyperlink or Picture (Url) types are not available. There is doesn't seem to be a way to look at a field has an unsupported type.

Are there plans to map all the types?
I've tried bot v1.0 APIs and beta APIs as well.

Request example:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/group-id/sites/root/columns
```

for, let's say, Text field I see `field` property:

```
"text": {
  "allowMultipleLines": false,
  "appendChangesToExistingText": false,
  "linesForEditing": 0,
  "maxLength": 255
}
```

But for Url, or Taxonomy, and some other types there is no indication at all.

Answer (score 1):

In currently, the Graph API can provide the type property of the ColumnDefinition resource.
Check the official document here: [ColumnDefinition resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/columndefinition?view=graph-rest-1.0).

As a workaround, we have to use SharePoint REST API to achieve it.

```
https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/lz/_api/web/Fields
```

Comment: I'm agree about `ColumnDefinition`. And the request from my question returns `ColumnDefinition` collection for the list. But in the documentation it's said **Note: These properties correspond to SharePoint's SPFieldType enumeration. While the most common field types are represented above, this API is still missing some. In those cases, none of the column type facets will be populated, and the column will only have its basic properties.** And my question was are there plans to include other types as well?

Comment: For the SharePoint REST API - it's completely another story as you need to get access token using another flow.